# how to unlock Thomson tg 585 v7 router?

Tags: router, updates, firmware

I have a Thomson tg 585 v7 router provided by Plusnet. So that the configuration page has the logo of Plusnet. I am on Ubuntu OS and need to use the router to connect for another ADSL provider. The router can not be connected to my current ISP. Is it a way to "unlock" the router? How?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change configurations when you use SET UP, try to RESTORE TO FACTORY SETTINGS, if it doesn't work, you need to contact your new ISP, and if you want another solution, maybe updating your firmware or downgrading, usually locked modems are locked as in the firmware.